# Accessing Android smartphone (Galaxy S3) via an unstable USB connection

Tags: debian, android

I'm attempting to connect to an Android smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S3) whose screen is broken (i.e. completely black) in order to save all files on it. The whole phone is (almost) completely beyond repair as the USB slot does not allow for a stable connection at all. Even though I already attempted to fixate the USB cable with duct tape (I'm not kidding), this is what I always end up with (according to dmesg):

> [  750.075987] usb 1-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
>
> [  750.186084] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
>
> [  750.186091] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>
> [  750.186095] usb 1-1.6: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
>
> [  750.186098] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
>
> [  750.186101] usb 1-1.6: SerialNumber: 9baf4266
>
> [  780.783212] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 14
>
> [  793.596612] usb 1-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
>
> [...]
>
> [  852.507428] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 15
>
> [  866.039114] usb 1-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
>
> [...]
>
> [  944.407661] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 16
>
> [...]

I.e. the connection is reset roughly every minute due to USB connection problems. I'm on Debian 9 and use libmtp. The command "mtp-detect" always fails with the following output:

> libmtp version: 1.1.13
>
> Listing raw device(s)
>
> Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
>
> Found 1 device(s):
>
> Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 14
>
> Attempting to connect device(s)
>
> PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
>
> LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
>
> inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
>
> outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
>
> libusb_open() failed!: No such device
>
> LIBMTP PANIC: Could not init USB on second attempt
>
> Unable to open raw device 0
>
> OK.

My question is: Is there any way to use `libmtp` (or any other free software) to (bash) copy files from my Android device to my laptop via an unstable connection? Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: If your device is connected to wifi and you have a permanent authorization to run adb command from your linux machine, You will be able to run `adb` command over wifi to download your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no means of checking whether wifi is activated or not as the phone's screen is completely black and inaccessible.

Comment: Install and use `arp-sacn` to check if the smartphone is connected to your router or not. The must important is to have the ADB enabled and a permanent permission to use it through  your debian machine.

Comment: I installed arp-scan but unfortunately I only get a segmentation fault every time I try to run it. This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan/issues/27) (at least for Ubuntu).

Comment: Use `nmap` or check your router settings it should be listed under the connected devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, nmap doesn't list my device as connected to the router.Thus, I really have to rely on USB.