# Copying folders from MTP device using libmtp (over USB)

Tags: debian, android

My question is very closely related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328665/copying-file-from-mtp-device-using-libmtp-over-usb) question:

How do I download complete folders (not only single files) with libmtp from an Android device to my laptop? I'm on Debian 9.

There is a [blog post](https://blog.darknedgy.net/technology/2014/08/10/0/) claiming that you could do this with "mtp-connect --getfolder ..." but there is no such option on my system.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. It is not the same problem because you can't connect correctly to your Android device , please edit the first question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447362/accessing-android-smartphone-galaxy-s3-via-an-unstable-usb-connection , it should be a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you very much for welcoming me. Even though it's actually true that I can't connect correctly to my device, I would like to copy some folders from the device once I find a way to deal with unstable USB connections. Thus, this is a separate questions and any answer might also be relevant for others.

Answer (score 0):

Debian 9 has `jmtpfs` package, which provides a way to mount an Android MTP device as a filesystem. It might be more convenient for you.

Note that as the man page for `jmtpfs` says, you should use `fusermount -u <mountpoint>` to unmount it once you're done. Just using the regular `umount` command won't shut down the user-space part of jmtpfs properly.

Answer (score 0):

mtp-connect is part of mtp-tools -

```
$ dpkg -L mtp-tools | grep mtp-connect
/usr/bin/mtp-connect
/usr/share/man/man1/mtp-connect.1.g
```

You might have to install mtp-tools in your system. The other part has been shared by our common friend upstairs.